# Is it possible to make real DIY microscope with several lens?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses, home-experiment, microscopy

I have alot of small double convex 7 mm lenses and i have very small lens 4mm
And i have plano concave lenses all of them is small
I tried to combining them to get a magnified image and it worked when i combien the smallest one with the other lenses
Is there any possible way to get more magnification?
And is there any advantage of the concave lens to make a diy microscope or all i need is just convex lenses??
Any idea please?

Comment: This may help [Stacking lenses for higher magnification (a DIY microscope)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228565/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 i actually visit that link before and i didn't get much info from it

Comment: You should say what the sizes of your lens are

Comment: @user14094230  The smallest one is 4mm (plano convex) and the small one is 7mm (double convex) and i have small plano convex maybe 7mm or 6mm and i have concave also